# Rails, Devise with omniauth-facebook auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials#_=_

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, omniauth

I have setup omniauth-facebook gem as follows on my development machine:

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'APP_KEY', '  APP_SECRET'
end
```

I have registered my app with facebook developers and provided a site url as "http://localhost:3000" as well as entering my APP_KEY and APP_SECRET into omniauth.rb

When i try to sign in, i get redirected to my root url saying `routing error No route matches [GET] "/auth/failure"` and in the url it says invalid credentials. I have been able to get omniauth Twitter, Github and Google to work, however Facebook is not logging me in. I am following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook). any thoughts?

Comment: i solved it, all i had to do was wait a while for facebook to update its servers.